# Serilog SqlServer Sinks Multiple Tables

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, serilog, sink

I'm using Serilog SQL Server Sink for .NET Core, and just wondering if it's possible to write logs to multiple data tables.

To write to a single table the configuration would be like:

```
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": "Information",
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "MSSqlServer",
      "Args": {
        "connectionString": "Data Source=XXX\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=XYZ;Integrated Security=True",
        "tableName": "Log"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want multiple tables in the same database? Or a different database? Why? Have you tried just adding another object to the WriteTo array and seeing what happens?

Comment: Multiple tables in same db e.g. Log and LogDetails(to  accommodate more information if needed). No I didn't try that but if I do that way how to call and specify table name in Log.Information() method?

Comment: You don't specify which table when you're actually logging things. With Serilog, you configure a logger to log to certain sinks. If you sometimes want to log to certain sinks but not others, then you'll need to configure separate loggers and stop using the static logger. But really, why do you even want to have one table with only some of the log and some with all of the detail? Just put it all in one place, then manage it by choosing which [logging level](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Writing-Log-Events#log-event-levels) you're logging at.

Comment: And if you're using Serilog, then I highly recommend using [Seq](https://getseq.net/) instead of the SQL Server sink. It makes filtering through your logs to find the details you want much easier.

Comment: @mason A separate table makes sense. I am logging errors to one table. But I need another table to replace the legacy logging of routine stuff that gets captured. There are columns which the team can't live without. And they differ wildly from the error log table. And burying them as JSON in the LogEvent column is not an option, as searching that is super slow.

Comment: @onefootswill perhaps you can write your own Serilog Sink to log exactly how you want. The interface is pretty simple.

Comment: How about configuring Serilog as described here - https://www.techrepository.in/blog/posts/split-log-data-different-tables-serilog-aspnet-core.